# Declaring a Class in ASPX Script Block Then Storing it in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble doing something that I think should be very doable. Perhaps someone can tell me what I'm missing.
I am restricted to adding my C# code to my .aspx page in a server-side script block (no code behind). I would like to define a new class (again without creating any other files) on the ASPX page (this would be a nested class) and then store a List of these objects in Session to persist between postbacks and after the user spends some time on other pages and then returns to the one in question.
Here's my code...

```
    <script language="C#" runat="Server">
    protected List<Part> AssignmentSearchResults
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["SearchResults"] == null)
                Session["SearchResults"] = new List<Part>();
            return (List<Part>)Session["SearchResults"];
        }
        set
        {
            Session["SearchResults"] = value;
        }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }

</script>
(html goes here)
```

If I use List it works just fine, but when I use my custom class it does not. Here is the error I get...

> [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ASP.pub_usercontrols_exeplanning_resources_ascx+Part] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ASP.pub_usercontrols_exeplanning_resources_ascx+Part]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

...and perhaps you'll note that the two (A and B) are completely identical.
Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: Try once again after deleting temp files from following locations :C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files and do the same for other framework versions too. And the same for following path : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

Comment: @Jeremy, do you obtain the same result if you define the `Part` class in `global.asax`?

Comment: I'll try both of these. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to, in theory, but at what point is that aspx getting turned into code, and namespace is that code being put into.  What is the reason to not put this class in a separate .cs file, where it belongs?

Comment: The aspx is getting turned into code when ASP.NET decides it should. It is given (again by ASP.NET) a namespace that derives from the page it's on as you can see in the error message (ASP.pub_usercontrols_exeplanning_resources_ascx+Part). Finally, the statement that the class belongs in a separate .cs file is a subjective one since script block code and nested classes are both technically correct methods of authoring code according to ASP.NET. That said, it would be better if it were separate, but as I mentioned I'm restricted in this case... business constraint... you know how it is.

Comment: Can you create new project with all classes you want to use in your web application, put generated dll into application's bin folder and register this assembly in web.config?

Comment: FYI, I had to deliver and was not able to try the suggestions above. I ended up just adding a ToString override to my custom class (Part) to serialize it and a constructor to deserialize it and then storing it in Session as a List<string>. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing your problem, but I have a solution.
Since session objects are being serialized anyway, why not serialize the object/list of objects first and then put it into Session[]?

IE:

```
List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
//... populate parts
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Part>));

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xs.Serialize(ms, parts);

// Rewind the stream and write it to session as XML

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Session["XMLResults"] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());

//Get memory stream from session
ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] bData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Session["XMLResults"].ToString());
ms.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);

// Hydrate parts list from a memory stream
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
parts = (List<Part>)xs.Deserialize(ms);
```

Comment: Thank you. That's much like what I did. I overloaded the ToString on my object (the Part object) and used DataContractSerializer to serialize it, and I added a constructor that takes a string (the serialized Part) which I deserialized and then initialized the properties with. Then I stored it in Session as a List<string>. Worked like a charm. Not quite as elegant as storing a List<Part> but it works :)